# Model moving when using automatic weights

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, weight-painting

When using the automatic weight option to attach the model to the rig, the model moves down and is attached, this only happened after modeling the spikes on the wings. Any ideas on how to prevent this?

[image]

Comment: maybe before parenting try to unparent the object? If it doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: This worked and had to move the model again to line it up. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Before parenting, unparent the object so that it moves to its real location, if your object is already parented the visual location is not the real one. If you want to unparent the object and keep it at its visual location, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Clear and Keep Transformation*.